# NSUserDefaults returns NSDictionary instead of NSArray

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

This is how I store the NSArray:

```
   let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    for item in data as NSArray {
        if let id = item["id"] as? String {
            defaults.setObject(item, forKey: "Content:" + id);
            defaults.synchronize();
        }
    }
```

But when I try to get the stored data, I had to use

```
if let content = defaults.dictionaryForKey("Content:" + contentID) {}
```

Otherwise the content is empty. But that would be ok if there would be an simple method to get this NSDictionary into an NSArray (as it is needed in some other classes, to which the data is handed over).

Is there something wrong by the way I store the NSArray? BTW: its an array where the keys are Strings. Something like String:AnyObject.

Thanks in advance!

Best
Stefan

Comment: thx eric, but I want to store the item itself, the id is to have an unique name for the object in the nsuserdefaults.

Comment: I meant: "data" is the array, "item" is a dictionary... :p

Comment: You are storing this as dictionary, then how can retrieve as array!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your objects are set just fine in user defaults, but you are saving dictionaries in user defaults (because your `item` is a dictionary), this is why you must use `defaults.dictionaryForKey`. You could store the whole array using

```
defaults.setObject(data as NSArray, forKey: "Some key");
```

Comment: You are completly right, the item is an NSDictionary. 

"I thought for item in data as NSArray" 

would cast the the item to NSArray. That was the fault. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if let id = item["id"] as? String
```

is highly suspecting. How come an Array item could generate a value from a key "id"? So I think you're not sure whether item is Array or Dictionary. You're storing Dictionary to userdefaults just because this line

```
for item in data as NSArray
```

is a success. That is a wrong approach. To make this clear, try the below code.

```
let mydictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    mydictionary.setValue("123", forKey: "abc")
    let data = [mydictionary]
    for item in data as NSArray {
        if let id = item["id"] as? String {

        }
    }
```

Here I am storing a NSMutableDictionary to data. And it is passing

```
for item in data as NSArray
```

I hope you undersatnd.